# how to get accurate or (near accurate) distance between two places? Mysql/PHP

Tags: mysql, geocoding

SELECT postcode, lat, lng,
    truncate(
        (degrees(acos
            (sin(radians(`lat`)) 
                * 
                sin( radians('.$latitude.')) 
                + 
                cos(radians(`lat`)) 
                * 
                cos( radians('.$latitude.')) 
                * 
                cos( radians(`lng` - ('.$longitude.'))) 
                ) 
            ) 
            * 69.172), 2) 
            as distance
            FROM `myData`
This query calculates distance (in miles). But when I check distance for same lat and longitude at google maps my result doesnt match. If the distance is around 10 miles then my result is a bit accurate, but over that it gets wrong (for example, my result showed 13 miles and google showed 22 miles for same post code values)

I got this query from http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?23,3868,3868#msg-3868

How can I get it accurate. Any ideas?
Thanks for help.

UPDATE

I tried @Blixt code in PHP. Picked up 2 sample postcodes and their lats longs

```
//B28 9ET
$lat1 = 52.418819;
$long1 = -1.8481053;

//CV5 8BX
$lat2 = 52.4125573;
$long2 = -1.5407743;

$dtr = M_PI / 180;
$latA = $lat1 * $dtr;
$lonA = $long1 * $dtr;
$latB = $lat2 * $dtr;
$lonB = $long2 * $dtr;
$EarthRadius = 3958.76; //miles
echo $distance = $EarthRadius * acos(cos($latA) * cos($latB) * cos($lonB - $lonA) + sin($latA) * sin($latB));
```

Results:

My app - 12.95 miles

Google - 17.8 miles

Any ideas how to get it right?

Comment: Are you sure Google doesn't take stuff like roads into account when calculating distances?

Comment: hmm .. may be because of this. I checked using Get directions on google maps. Is there any formula to get something similiar to Googles?

Comment: There is no formula to take roads into account, other than some kind of average bird distance/drive distance ratio that will be wrong 99% of the time. You'll need to use an API that lets you get the road distance in that case. Have a look at the Google Maps API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this source code](http://code.google.com/p/blixt/source/browse/trunk/cs/GpsLocation/GpsLocation.cs). When I tested it against various other measurement services it seemed to get the same results. It's C# but the math should be easy enough to convert.

Here are the relevant pieces:

```
public const double EarthRadius = 6371.0072; // Kilometers
//public const double EarthRadius = 3958.76; // Miles

/* ... */

const double dtr = Math.PI / 180;
double latA = this.Latitude * dtr;
double lonA = this.Longitude * dtr;
double latB = other.Latitude * dtr;
double lonB = other.Longitude * dtr;

return GpsLocation.EarthRadius * Math.Acos(Math.Cos(latA) * Math.Cos(latB) * Math.Cos(lonB - lonA) + Math.Sin(latA) * Math.Sin(latB));
```

**Note:** The Earth is not perfectly spherical, so the constants used may differ. There is no easy way to make the measurements truly exact. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Blixt. 

//B28 9ET
$lat1 = 52.418819;
$long1 = -1.8481053;

//CV5 8BX
$lat2 = 52.4125573;
$long2 = -1.5407743;

$dtr = M_PI / 180;
$latA = $lat1 * $dtr;
$lonA = $long1 * $dtr;
$latB = $lat2 * $dtr;
$lonB = $long2 * $dtr;
$EarthRadius = 3958.76; //miles
echo $distance = $EarthRadius * acos(cos($latA) * cos($latB) * cos($lonB - $lonA) + sin($latA) * sin($latB));

Result: 
my app = 12.95~ miles
Google = 17.8 miles

--  :-(  --

Comment: @Blixt - is it possible for you to check the above values in your application? If yes, can you please let me know what values you get?

Comment: I have checked and I get the same values as you, and I verified it with a few other services on the internet and they also returned the same values. How are you checking the distance with Google Maps?

Comment: Now I've even put the two coordinates on the map in Google Maps and used the "My Maps" feature to drag a line between the two points and sure enough, it shows ~13 miles. So the error probably lies in how you measure the distance with Google.

Comment: hmm .. It is Google Maps get directions.

Comment: Oh well then it is not strange! Get directions measures the distance to drive from one place to another (i.e. it follows the roads), this method calculates the point-to-point distance. Measuring the drive distance between two points is far more complex than what you have here.

Comment: ah I see. Thanks, Blixt. I need to find about that "complex" formula.

Comment: Oh by complex I don't mean just complex. I mean immensely difficult, bordering on impossible for an individual. You'd have to have a database of all roads to start with. Just use an API instead. See my comment on your question.